# NTAG 424 AuthenticationEV2 First NULL response

Tags: authentication, nfc

I am currently developing an application using Flutter to write to an NTAG424 DNA NFC tag; however, I am encountering some issues with the keys. The keys become unusable after a while, and I must switch to the other key to authenticate.

For instance, I was using keyNo 0 to authenticate, but after a while, the response I receive from the NTAG is null, and I must authenticate with another key.

Best regards, Shaghayegh

Comment: The error might be in line 42 of your invisible source code, sorry.

Comment: @michael-fehr Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.